# Analog to the Gay-Lussac free expansion experiment for a gas of photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

Can the experiment of Gay-Lussac and Joule on the free expansion of (ideal) gas be repeated for 'light' (gas of photons)?

Comment: Which experiment are you referring to? Some of the problems with imagining light as a gas (in a vacuum) are that photons can't actually bounce off other photons as ideal gases can and that photons do not actually have a well-defined temperature.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Gay-Lussac's 1807 experiment. I understand what happens (Wien's law) but would like to know 'practically' how to realize the experiment.

Comment: If that's the study done on the change in temperature of the gas during free expansion, then no: light doesn't have a temperature!

Comment: Blackbody mixture of light has a temperature. You have to think 'effective temperature'.

Comment: Is the container you're using a black body or a white body (all light is reflected off the sides, analogous to how all ideal gas molecules are reflected off the sides)? I'll vote your question up because I'm curious if there's an answer.